# I am having trouble building a Rock Paper Scissors Game (Best out of 3 version)

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am new to Python and am currently up-skilling myself. I am trying to build a best out of 3 version of Rock Paper Scissors - here is my attempt.

Why is this not working?

I am trying to create 2 new variables players_win and computer_wins to count the number of wins and then use that to define whether I've won a best out of 3 game, not sure if the way in which I've used "or" in the while loop is correct either - I don't think the variable increases are being picked up.

## Rock Scissors Paper game (Best out of 2 version)

```
from random import randint

t = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissor"]

print("Hi, what is your name?")
player_wins = 0
computer_wins = 0
games_played = 0
myName = input()

print(f"Hi {myName}, Lets play a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors - actually make that a best out of 3! Lets do this")

computer = t[randint(0,2)]

player = False

while (computer_wins < 3 or player_wins < 3):
    player_wins = 0
    computer_wins = 0
    games_played = 0

    player = input()

    games_played = games_played + 1

    if player == computer:
        print("thats a tie! again!")
    elif player == "Rock":
        if computer == "Paper":
            print("You lose!", computer, "covers", f"{myName}")
            computer_wins = computer_wins + 1
        else:
            print("You win!", f"{myName}", "smashes", computer)
            player_wins = player_wins + 1
    elif player == "Paper":
        if computer == "Scissor":
            print("You lose", computer, "slices", f"{myName}")
            computer_wins = computer_wins + 1
        else:
            print("You win", f"{myName}", "cover", computer)
            player_wins = player_wins + 1
    elif player == "Scissor":
        if computer == "Rock":
            print("You lose!", computer, "smashes", f"{myName}")
            computer_wins = computer_wins + 1
        else:
            print("You win!", f"{myName}", "slices", computer)
            player_wins = player_wins + 1
    else:
        print(f"Thats not a valid play {myName}! Check your spelling!")

    print(games_played)

    player = False
    computer = t[randint(0,2)]

    print(player_wins)
    print(computer_wins)
    print(games_played)
    if player_wins == 2:
        print(f"Well done {myName}, you won!")
    else:
        print(f"Unlucky {myName}, you lost!")
```

Comment: It should probably be: `while computer_wins < 3 and player_wins < 3:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't end the while loop because you set `player_wins` and `computer_wins`  to 0 after every round. Also you set `games_played` to 0 though that isn't a confition to the loop:
To fix this you need to change this:

```py
while (computer_wins < 3 or player_wins < 3):
    player_wins = 0
    computer_wins = 0
    games_played = 0
    …
```

to

```py
player_wins = 0
computer_wins = 0
games_played = 0
while (computer_wins < 3 or player_wins < 3):
    …
```

PS:
Good luck with learning python. To write a little less you could use `var += 1` instead of `var = var + 1`. See [Python References](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/addition_assignment.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

At first: In the while loop use      and      instead of or.

Next, don't set the

```
   player_wins = 0
   computer_wins = 0
   games_played = 0
```

variables inside the while loop. 
If you set them to 0 inside the loop, after each "round" you will start a new game.

The shorten for of increasing the variable value looks like this:

```
  player_wins += 1
```

It's the same as player_wins = player_wins +1

Comment: If you want to improve the game a bit, set the variables to 0 after the while loop ended. Then if somebody wins, the game will start again.